# Querying many tables at once using wildcards?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contain employee data from many branch offices. Each branch office would have one table assigned, so the structure would be like this

Employee_Database
 - branch_987158
 - branch_159785
 - branch_359752
 - etc ( until approx. 360 branch with 6 digit numeric code as identity )

The question is, can I use it like this : `select * from branch_* where jobID='A14'` to query all the branch tables at once?

Comment: No. Best way you can do is to restructure your table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of wildcards in mysql table name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612494/use-of-wildcards-in-mysql-table-name)

Comment: @JohnWoo I can't do that, this database structure is defined by our software development centre of my department.