# Prepared Statements extra quotes

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

When using prepared statements in Java, the method for replacing question marks with strings puts extra quotes that mess up my query. Here's the code I use:

```
ConnectToDB c = new ConnectToDB();
Connection conn = c.connectToDB();

String query = "select * from ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "users");

ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();

while(set.next()){
    users.add(new Utente(set.getInt("id"),
                         set.getString("name"),
                         set.getString("surname"),
                         set.getString("email"),
                         set.getString("password"),
                         set.getString("imgURL"),
                         set.getString("orgURL"),
                (Boolean)set.getObject("isAuthor")));
}

stmt.close();
```

Here's my log: apparently, when calling stmt.setString(1, "users") replaces ? with the string 'users', including the quotes:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1
```

I've tried to look for this problem but seems like everybody wants to include quotes into their statements and, apparently, nobody has my problem. I'm probably missing something dumb, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to use a parameter as the *table-name*. I don't know about MySQL, but most databases don't let you do this.

Comment: This is generally not possible, you can use the `?` in the `WHERE` clause, but as far as I know, not in other parts of the SQL statment. You have to use a `StringBuilder` or direct `String` concatenation for that (bad, I know).

Comment: @deHaar Additionally, you cannot use `?` as the parameter in the `WHERE` clause such as `? = ?` it can only be for the value such as `author = ?`

Comment: @Nexevis yes, right, thanks... I don't even know if it is valid in `HAVING`, but maybe it is.

Comment: Also you would benefit from researching `try-with` resources to automatically close `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, or `ResultSet`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612494/use-of-wildcards-in-mysql-table-name) that explains it thoroughly. Post your comment as an answer please, so that idiots like me can find the answer right away

Comment: @Nexevis Yes I did it of course, I omitted part of the code for brevity's sake

Comment: @mootasa `stmt.close()` gave me the impression that it was not used, so thought I would add the info just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it your table is called `users`. You don't use parameters for DB object names, just for *values* you're feeding into a query. So in your case, you'd just put `users` in the actual SQL:

```
String query = "select * from users";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();
```

(Or in this **particular** case, you could use `Statement` rather than `PreparedStatement` because you're not using any parameters.)

Presumably, `users` isn't a string you're getting from outside your program (e.g., not something you're getting from a user).

You'd use a parameter if you needed to provide a value, such as the ID of a user:

```
String query = "select * from users where id = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, userId);

ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();
```

---

Side note: Rather than calling `close` directly, as [Nexevis said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891884/prepared-statements-extra-quotes#comment102205399_57891884), I suggest using try-with-resources. That would look like this:

```
String query = "select * from users";
ConnectToDB c = new ConnectToDB();
try (
    Connection conn = c.connectToDB();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
) {
    ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();

    while(set.next()){
        users.add(new Utente(set.getInt("id"),
                             set.getString("name"),
                             set.getString("surname"),
                             set.getString("email"),
                             set.getString("password"),
                             set.getString("imgURL"),
                             set.getString("orgURL"),
                    (Boolean)set.getObject("isAuthor")));
    }
}
```